# Errors on updating the CMS

Tags: updates

I am working on my first Craft CMS website. The website owner notified me this weekend, his website is out of the Google index. Found there is this bug https://github.com/craftcms/cms/issues/9621
Can't believe how something like this can happen :-(

Anyway. I now wanted to update, but there seems to be another bug with Composer (exhausted memory).

So I made a fresh copy locally and tried to update. Now the local copy doesn't work at all. There was an error 500 during the update.

How is this CMS to update? Starting to think it was quite a bad decision trying this CMS :-|

v 3.5.19.1
PHP 7.4
mac locally, Ubuntu 18 web server with Apaxche 2.4

Comment: Can you let us know how you're performing the update? Via CLI `craft update`, or via the CP interface? I'd recommend using the CLI. Also, I'd recommend using Composer v2 if you aren't already.